# disable entities in jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery

I need to disable entities in ajax/jquery... is there any way to do this?

example when a user inputs a link, once it is process by the script alot of characters are replaced.
I will paste that part of the link after the .com/ here.

```
onthefarm/track.php?creative&cat=feed&subcat=mystery_seeds_complete&key=6f8d7bfafa5b157aa29c0e3920630cad%24%24idG%21N-OS1YyMY4M9yNJE.1bz%2AYXsMyRHY5Byhuf6vqhE3eFtP48kKVdp7C%2AVbI4NJ&next=reward.php%3FfrHost%3D711208004%26frId%3D9jzg1otryxc8skg4gkko8kgs8%26frType%3DConstructionBuildingFriendReward%26key%3D6f8d7bfafa5b157aa29c0e3920630cad%24%24idG%21N-OS1YyMY4M9yNJE.1bz%2AYXsMyRHY5Byhuf6vqhE3eFtP48kKVdp7C%2AVbI4NJ&ref=nf
```

I have successfully "kept the & sign" by using %26 before sending it to ajax/jquery. If you take the time to look at this link you will see there are alot of %24, $21, among other things that will be replaced so my temporary solution was to add this code after...

```
   $text = str_replace("%26", "&", $text);
   $text = str_replace("*", "%2A", $text);
   $text = str_replace("(", "%28", $text);
   $text = str_replace(",", "%2C", $text);
   $text = str_replace("$", "%24", $text);
   $text = str_replace("reward.php?", "reward.php%3F", $text);
   $text = str_replace("frHost=", "frHost%3D", $text);
   $text = str_replace("&frId=", "%26frId%3D", $text);
   $text = str_replace("&frType=", "%26frType%3D", $text);
   $text = str_replace("FriendReward&key=", "FriendReward%26key%3D", $text);
```

I had to do it this way so that it is done one at a time, as you see in the url there are  insances of "&key" and "%26key" one is supposed to be "%26key" and one is supposed to "&key". If I can just tell the script to not urlencode.

It is not a database issue, I put the information in with a standard form that doesn't use jquery/ajax and the information is stored in the database exactly as the user put it in.

Comment: can you provide a code example, and a little more explanation. I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: I have a form, that uses jquery ajax to post the input to the server, it is cutting out the & sign, and anything that follows behind it, I am not sure what code you want to see, the ajax, the form, or the messa_ajax script...

Comment: I would be more than happy to show all of it, I can show you [mysite](http://www.fvfools.com) and [another](http://www.fvfools.com/fb) if you type in me & you, it only post me... I was thinking since both scripts used the same language it was maybe an issue. At the end of the ajax/javascript, where it is sending the values, to the message_ajax i put alert(message_val) and the full link was there, which told me it didn't get changed there... I have tried everything I can think of to find where its changing it and why.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to URL encode your text. The "&" symbol would be %26, see here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: I tried $message=rawurlencode($message); and this is what I got... when I typed you & me. you%20 Like I said its not a database issue, cause if I use a regular form to submit it, it goes into the database fine, and at the end of the javascript/ajax that posts the information back to the browser, i put alert(message_val) and it printed the correct information... so I'm not exactly sure where in the script its getting changed.

Comment: this is where my script is located, you will need to login via facebook, [link](http://www.fvfools.com) you can see the posts that I put in with the plain form the full url is there, and see the ones with rawurlencode(), and the one with the cutoffs as well... also on this one the comments don't work.  Here is another one too [link](http://www.fvfools.com/fb) this one the comments work. Thank you very much

Comment: THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! so much!!! it did it :) I searched and found a function because the urlencode didnt remove &, thanks!!!

Comment: well I thought it would work, once I got it to replace & with %26, jquery replaced alot of things, the urls that will be used have a lot of % signs, that don't mean anything.... Is there a way to tell the jquery code to not change characters, or would I have to edit the jquery script... it would be nice I could say message=$(#message).val().dontchangeit... thanks

Comment: here is a sample url..... http://apps.facebook.com/onthefarm/track.php?creative&cat=feed&subcat=mystery_seeds_halfway&key=23f6f3993948058443eb815586a5eae0%24%24ccI3W%2CST02bNY5%2AUzNKZxXhyeLQ%28gMRIJBlr5q9ocKhE3eFtOa2pEZdp7C%2AVbI4NJ&next=reward.php%3FfrHost%3D1037964134%26frId%3Daqq4fn9icbcc4ck4sk4k08s44%26frType%3DConstructionBuildingFriendReward%26key%3D23f6f3993948058443eb815586a5eae0%24%24ccI3W%2CST02bNY5%2AUzNKZxXhyeLQ%28gMRIJBlr5q9ocKhE3eFtOa2pEZdp7C%2AVbI4NJ&ref=nf

Comment: I think you want to use the javascript escape and unescape for this.  Take a look at http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm

Answer (score 1):

`&` has a special meaning in URLs, separating parameters. it may need to be escaped before being sent into `urlencode`, or that is why it is being separated there. idk just a theory

Comment: i went thru and decoded as much as could of the urls, here is the code i had to use.. after I replaced & with %26, I had to go back in and put it back so it gets pulled of database...as %26, and alot of other wrong characters...

Comment: $text = str_replace("%26", "&", $text);
       $text = str_replace("*", "%2A", $text);
       $text = str_replace("(", "%28", $text);
       $text = str_replace(",", "%2C", $text);
       $text = str_replace("$", "%24", $text);
       $text = str_replace("reward.php?", "reward.php%3F", $text);
       $text = str_replace("frHost=", "frHost%3D", $text);
       $text = str_replace("&frId=", "%26frId%3D", $text);
       $text = str_replace("&frType=", "%26frType%3D", $text);
       $text = str_replace("FriendReward&key=", "FriendReward%26key%3D", $text);

Comment: and some of the links still don't work, if I could just tell either AJAX or JQUERY not to change it, it would be a life saver.

Comment: well you probably need to decode the URL on the server side, where it gets put into the database. Can you use POST instead of GET? that would eliminate this whole issue.

Comment: and whoa whoa whoa, all that code?? There is DEFINITIVELY a function that already will do that for you. Unless you are writing an Ajax library, that is not the way you should be going about it.

Comment: something is going wrong either client or server side, check the PHP scripts that is probably where the error is if nothing is obvious in the js. At least check it first, I'm so confused by this whole question, and all these comments. omg

Comment: its not doing it to just urls. it is doing it to "you & me", but I fixed that, and in my search learned that jquery/ajax automatically does "entities" I need it not to.